# Cakephp 3 Auth Component $this->Auth->password() not working

Tags: cakephp-3.0

i want to update my password with users table and in cakephp 2.0 i am using like that --

```
$haspass = $this->Auth->password($pass);
```

working fine but in cakephp3 it`s not working..

Answer (score 0):

finally i have found the solution --

In Controller -- Use Like That

```
use Cake\Auth\DefaultPasswordHasher;
use Cake\ORM\Entity;

$password = $_POST['new_pswd'];
$hashPswdObj = new DefaultPasswordHasher;
$hashpswd = $hashPswdObj->hash($password); // it will hash the password
```

Comment: You may want to continue with reading **http://book.cakephp.org/3.0/en/controllers/request-response.html**, as using `$_POST` usually isn't the way how you read posted data in CakePHP.